# Convert the string having millseconds/microsecond to a 'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss' in oracle

Tags: oracle

I  have string = '07-Jun-2021 23:30:43.758'  .
how can i convert it into '2020-06-07 23:30:43'

i tried casting or converting using to_date /to_timestamp. its not giving desired result.

Comment: Do you really need `07-Jun-2021` converted into `2020-06-07` (one year less)?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a timestamp, then back to a string.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_TIMESTAMP ('07-Jun-2021 23:30:43.758', 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'),
                'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM DUAL;
```